# can't setup gunicorn - django

Tags: django, gunicorn

I am trying to setup gunicorn with django according to this [blog](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/). I have created the `gunicorn_start` script and also gave permission to the user as described in the blog. I can start gunicorn by running this command:

```
$ gunicorn hello.wsgi:application --bind example.com:8001
```

But, I can't when I run this command as in the blog:

```
$ sudo su - hello
$ bin/gunicorn_start
```

It returns this:

```
$ sudo su - hello
$ bin/gunicorn_start
-su: 1: bin/gunicorn_start: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

gunicorn_start is a script that you create yourself in those instructions, halfway down the page.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention it in my question. But I have already created it and also gave the user its permission. And after that I ran the above command. I have updated my question.